# How to remove an entire table using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a calendar table, that shows the entire month's date, if user chose to see next month or previous I need to delete the entire table and replace the new table in that same place, at the moment each table is loading underneath the other because I cant get this to work.

I need to remove table from calendar-dates. but I had no luck. I have used **removechild("tb")** but didnt work, I also tried var **test = document.getElementById("calendarDates");
                    test.removeChild(test.childNodes[0]);**

Here is the code for the table:

```
document.getElementById("calendar-dates").appendChild(calendar);
```

Table:

```
 //add calendar table
    function get_calendar(day_no, days, m , y){
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.id = "tb";
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        //row for the day letters
        for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = "SMTWTFS"[c];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);

        //create 2nd row
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var c;
        for(c=0; c<=6; c++){
            if(c == day_no){
                break;
            }
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = "";
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        var count = 1;
        for(; c<=6; c++){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = count;
            td.style.cursor = "pointer";
            td.id = count;
            td.onclick = function () {
                m = m + 1;
                document.getElementById("cDD").value = this.id + "/" + m + "/" + y;
                document.getElementById("calendar-container").style.display = "none";

            };
            count++;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);

        //rest of the date rows
        for(var r=3; r<=7; r++){
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
                if(count > days){
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                    return table;
                }
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = count;
                td.style.cursor = "pointer";
                td.id = count;
                td.onclick = function () {
                    m = m + 1;
                    document.getElementById("cDD").value = this.id + "/" + m + "/" + y;
                    document.getElementById("calendar-container").style.display = "none";
                };
                count++;
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to use code snippet , you want fast answer.

Comment: Where is the HTML? Did you notice that you can make your code runnable? Much easier to help if you have running code.

Comment: @Nikola see website just added it to the question

Comment: @Luke We should not need to look outside of this site. Code should be posted here. In any case, I added a running example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `removeChild` method takes a node, not an ID.
- `test.removeChild(test.childNodes[0]);` probably doesn't work because you have some text nodes before the table.

  - `test.removeChild(test.firstElementChild)`probably will work

`document.getElementById("calendar-dates").removeChild(document.getElementById('tb'))`

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').removeChild(document.querySelector('table'));
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button>Remove table</button>
```

Comment: OK I will try this one I will let you  know if it works

Comment: Cheers thank you it did work :) The problem was I was trying to delete the nodes. I didnt realised you could call document.getelement.. inside the removeChild. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does `#calendar-dates` contains other html than tables? If not, you can set `innerHtml` to empty

```
var calendarDates = document.getElementById("calendar-dates");

calendarDates.innerHtml = '';
calendarDates.appendChild(calendar);
```

Comment: An answer is more helpful if it explains what the problem was with the OP's code. Just solving it a different way doesn't help them learn.